# How to make Tkinter app work on different computers with different resolutions

Tags: python, tkinter, ttkwidgets

I have a tkinter app program written and everything works without getting errors. I converted the tkinter .py to a .exe by using `pyinstaller`. This application should be able to access through remote computers (desktops or laptops). But the problem is when trying remote desktop, the app won't open.

I think it's because I used `.place()` to place the widgets and `x` , `y` values are not the same for each computer. But I am also having some plots which are clearing by a button press. For that, `.get_tk_widget().place_forget()` is much easier and works well. And I know that I cannot mix `grid` and `place` in the same program.

How can I make the program work with any computer after converting to a .exe? The following is a simplified example of a much longer code.

````
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkmacosx import Button
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg)
import numpy as np

plt.close("all")

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent,bg='#192232') 
        toolbar0 = tk.Frame(self,bg="#393951")
        toolbar0.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        label = ttk.Label(toolbar0, text="OLE Analyser")
        label.pack(pady=7,padx=10)
        button = Button(toolbar0, text="Analysis",command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.place(x=1600,y=6)   

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent,bg='#192232')
        toolbar1 = tk.Frame(self,bg="#393951")
        toolbar1.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        
        button1 = Button(toolbar1,text="Home",command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.place(x=1600,y=6)
        button2 = Button(toolbar1,text="Comparison",command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.place(x=1700,y=6) 

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9.05,6.43))
        canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,self) 
        
        x1 = np.arange(1,100,2)
        y1 = x1**2 
        ax.plot(x1,y1)
        canvas1.draw()
        canvas1.get_tk_widget().place(x=272,y=103)
        
        def clear_graph():
            canvas1.get_tk_widget().place_forget() 
            
        clear_btn = Button(self,text="Clear Graph",command=lambda:clear_graph())
        clear_btn.place(x=165,y=927)        
   
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent,bg='#192232')
        toolbar2 = tk.Frame(self,bg="#393951")
        toolbar2.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Window()             
    ww = 1920
    hw = 1009
                
    w = app.winfo_screenwidth()
    h = app.winfo_screenheight() 
        
    x = (w/2) - (ww/2)-8
    y = (h/2) - (hw/2)-36
            
    app.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (ww, hw, x, y))
    app.update()
    app.mainloop()```
````

Comment: "And I know that I cannot mix grid and place in the same program." ~ Yes you can. You cannot mix `grid` and `pack` in the same **widget**. ie. If you use `pack` in a `frame` you cannot also use `grid` in that same `frame`. You can use `place` all you like, regardless.

Comment: If I use `grid`, can I still use custom places for different `x`s and `y`s? And will it resolve the problem of not working the code in different computers?

Comment: `grid` is used to align widgets with a row/column approach. `pack` is  used to "dock" widgets to an available edge, even if that edge is created by another widget. `place` is used to put widgets at specific x/y coordinates. I do not understand your question, and I do not know if it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

My best answer to this question is that you set app.geometry to a specific number, such as;

```
app.geometry("800x600")
```

Using this, you can possibly alter your x and y values to bring them into such a frame, allowing for superfluous usage across resolutions. Also, depending on your use case, using

```
grid()
```

may be more appropriate than your current button implementation method, as it creates less room for your x & y values to be terribly off in a program that doesn't necessarily rely on x & y precise placement.